# How can I create a loop that reveals a certain number of labels?

Tags: vb.net

I want to be able to reveal and then populate a certain number of labels. The inefficient way would be to SELECT CASE on the number of labels required and then populate these in turn. I am looking for something like this:

```
For i = 1 to RequiredNumOfLabels
    Label & i.visible = true
    Label & i.text = DataTable.Rows(i).Item(2)
Next
```

Thank you.

EDIT:

```
    For i = 1 To NumberOfItems
        Dim lbl = Controls("lbl" & i)
        lbl.Visible = True
        lbl.Text = CStr(DataTable.Rows(i).Item(2))
    Next
```

I think the line

```
    Dim lbl = Controls("lbl" & i)
```

is the problem as after the line is executed, lbl still equals nothing.

The reasoning behind it is that I was trying to create an invoice generator in vb.net and I was hoping that this would be a simple way to do it - count the amount of items in the order, populate the labels with the names of the items, reveal that many labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your label controls are really in order like that, you can try just referencing them from a list:

```
Dim myLabels As New List(Of Label)
myLabels.Add(Label1)
myLabels.Add(Label2)
```

Then just update them:

```
For i as Integer = 1 to myLabels.Count
  myLabels(i - 1).Visible = True
  myLabels(i - 1).Text = DataTable.Rows(i).Item(2).ToString
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get controls by name through the forms `Controls` property

```
For i = 1 To RequiredNumOfLabels
    Dim lbl = TryCast(Controls("Label" & i), Label)
    If lbl IsNot Nothing Then
        lbl.Visible = True
        lbl.Text = CStr(DataTable.Rows(i).Item(2))
    End If
Next
```

Since you get an object of type `Control`, you have to cast it to `Label`.

---

UPDATE

It seems that you only use properties that are defined in `Control` anyway. Therfore you can simplify the code to

```
For i = 1 To RequiredNumOfLabels
    Dim lbl = Controls("Label" & i)
    lbl.Visible = True
    lbl.Text = CStr(DataTable.Rows(i).Item(2))
Next
```

Comment: I've tried this, but whenever I use it, lbl is always nothing - why is this?

Comment: Are you labels really of type `Label`? or did you use `TextBoxes`? Since all controls have a `Visible` and a `Text` property you could also just work with controls.

Comment: They are all Labels, yes. I tried your update and am getting error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on the third line of coding in your update.

Comment: Probably the control you are referring to does not exist. Are your labels really named "Label1", "Label2", etc. up to `RequiredNumOfLabels`? Rename them if not!

Comment: In my coding I have changed `Label` in `Dim lbl = Controls("Label" & i)` to the corresponding label name (and yes they do go up to `RequiredNumOfLabels`) so I'm not sure what the problem is - if you hadn't guessed by now I'm quite new to the programming scene so I thank you for sticking through my dumbness!

Comment: My code example looks for labels named `Label1`, `Label2`, `Label3`, etc. The name of the labels on your form must actually match these names. If you click on a label on your form, you can see its name in the properties window under the `(Name)` property. Do not confuse with the `Text` property. If `i` is `5`, then `"Label" & i` yields the label name `Label5`.

Comment: I've edited the original post to contain what I have changed it to. The labels are `lbl1`, `lbl2`, `lbl3` etc. I'm starting to wonder if there's a totally better way of doing it all together. The reasoning behind it is that I was trying to create an invoice generator in vb.net and I was hoping that this would be a simple way to do it - count the amount of items in the order, populate the labels with the names of the items, reveal that many labels.

Comment: Of cause then my code would have to be `Dim lbl = Controls("lbl" & i)`. Well, the standard way to handle this kind of situation would be to use a `DataGridView`. Another option is the `DataRepeater` of the `Visual Basic PowerPacks`, which is included in newer versions of VS.